# How do I publish to the group of people who liked a webpage or object?

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

So I similar question was asked about a year an half ago here:

[How do you programmatically publish to the Facebook feed associated with a 'liked' page?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3964199/how-do-you-programmatically-publish-to-the-facebook-feed-associated-with-a-like)

Since then facebook has changed somethings (I know shock). If you don't want to read that other question, what I'm trying to do is publish a message to all people who liked a certain webpage (a website with a like button). The method described in the answer no longer works. I haven't seen facebook say any where that they don't official support this (I know shock, again). Am I missing something completely obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found out how to do this. This link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol describes how to post an update to users who have liked your webpage. Here's the curl command:

`curl -F 'access_token=...'  -F 'message=Hello Likers'  -F 'id=http://www.myopengraphpage.com/page1.html'  https://graph.facebook.com/feed`

This command doesn't work and to make it work you need to use the open graph id of the object instead of the URL for the id parameter. You get the id of the URL from the graph API like this: http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.myopengraphpage.com/page1.html

Answer (score 0):

When you make a post to your facebook page, all people who like it will be able to see that post on their wall (depending on security settings and sorting choices).  You can either have the page admin post something or you can do it programmatically using a PAGE access token.  See the page login part of http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

**EDIT**

Based upon the edits to the original question changing from Facebook page to "website page", I have a new answer.  The answer is: sorry, you cannot.

Comment: I'm not talking about a page. I'm talking about an open graph object. Typically it's a website with the meta tags og:title, og:type, etc.

Comment: I could see why you were confused by the title, I changed it to make it clearer.

Comment: "what I'm trying to do is publish a message to all people who liked a certain page" -- from inside of your question.  What I posted will work.  I have pages that I programmatically post to too, and this works like a champ.

Comment: What I mean by "page" there is a webpage. I know that this works for facebook pages. I want to do the same thing for open graph objects which are websites.

Comment: See edit above to my response.  Thank you for editing your question to make the distinction more clear.  :)

Comment: Lol, thanks for taking the time. Sorry for the confusion, I've been at this a while and all these different concepts are swimming around my head, sometimes it's hard to get them straight.

Comment: Does that answer your question now?

Comment: Actually no, I was doing more research and you can post using the method mentioned in the previous question, but instead of using a URL for the id you need the Graph API ID. I'm trying to get the ID for one of my URLs and is not returning an ID. Another issue I'm having is that I can't find the feed once I do post =(. So I know it's possible, just haven't found out how yet.

Comment: Hmmm, I've never heard of this.  I've not heard of using the ids from a website and being able to post to them in some fashion.  Is there a working example of this somewhere? I like learning new stuff.  Sorry I misunderstood your question originally.

Comment: In this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/ if you scroll down to publishing they give you the curl command to publish to liked webpages. I assume that what you post goes to their feed, but so far I haven't been able to find it anywhere

Comment: please, a working example of what you're trying to attempt to do, not something so I can see it action please.

Comment: I suggest you try it yourself. I have a working sample, but I cannot post it here in a public forum (it's for my workplace). It's hard to find examples of this since facebook no longer promotes it and people are not really talking about it. I'm sure facebook will remove this feature soon enough.